# US stay of 90 days - return after 40 days both under ESTA

Tags: esta, repeat-visits

I traveled to the US from Germany and spent 90 days there to visit my girlfriend. I’ve been out of the country and in Germany for 40 days now and I have plans of returning for another week or two. How feasible is this? I have proof of a lease back home, and I’m also pre-enrolled into a German university for the next Fall semester. I’m of course going to have a return flight. I do not have a job however. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is no 90/180 rule in the US like there's in Germany. You should be fine.

If it becomes a regular thing that you repeatedly come for long stays and short absences they might start asking questions, but it's not illegal on it's own.

Comment: Do you think this is a cause for suspicion? I’ve seen posts about people staying in the US for 90 days, only to leave for a week or two and get another 90. This is obviously a longer time out than that, but still less than how long I was in the US for. Would this by itself make me go through second inspection?

Comment: @Karl it's up to the CBP officer, I can't guarantee anything, but from what you've told I doubt it.